# Turning a matrix into a table

Tags: python, pandas

I created a matrix of Spearman correlation values using

`pd.DataFrame.corr`

Now I´m trying to turn this matrix into a table with the columns X-Value, Y-Value and Spearman correlation coefficient. So that I can rank it by the highest coefficients.

Can anyone help me transform the matrix into the 3 column table?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.corr(method='spearman').stack().to_frame(name='correlation')
```

A more sophisticated way that also deletes duplicates is:

```
correlations = df.corr(method='spearman')

correlation_table = (
    correlations.where(
        np.triu(np.ones(correlations.shape), k=0)
        .astype(bool)
    )
    .stack()
    .to_frame(name='correlation')
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If I export this table to excel I just get the correlation coefficients without the x and y values (in this case the parameters correlated). How can I fix that?

Comment: are you getting merged cells or just no index?

Comment: Just no index in excel. If I use print() I can see the indices

Comment: Make sure `index` argument is set to True e.g  `correlation_table.to_excel('correlations.xlsx', index=True)` or try reseting the index before saving the excel file `correlation_table.reset_index().to_excel('correlations.xlsx')`